# Informix JDBC - fail to run sql update using JDBC, but ok when run using dbaccess

Tags: jdbc, utf-8, informix, character-set

The value to update contains 1 Arabic-like character ie ݠ .
Unicode point number is U+0760 (I get it from https://unicode.scarfboy.com/)

If the SQL is run using dbaccess the update works.
If the character is replaced with different arabic character, the update works both in JDBC and dbaccess. DB_LOCALE is en_US.utf8 . Thank you in advance.

The table

```
create table tbl_demo_1
(
    id serial not null,
    address varchar(100),
    primary key(id)
);
insert into tbl_demo_1 values (1,'somevalue');
```

The SQL

```
update tbl_demo_1
set address2 = 'BT. 8 ݠ MAIN ROAD'
where id = 1;
```

OS, IDS, JDK, JDBC

- OS  : CentOS 8
- IDS : IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10.FC4W1DE
- JDK : 1.8.0_172
- JDBC: 4.10.14, 4.50.7
- SQL client: SQuirrel SQL client, SQL Workbench/J

Comment: Can you please make the table schema and the UPDATE statement self-consistent?  The column names are not the same.  Do you happen to have the Unicode code point number (U+XXXX) for the troublesome character?  Is it a recent addition to Unicode, do you know?

Comment: Unicode point number is U+0760. I'm not sure if it is a recent addition, how do i check?

Comment: I think the UTF8 database has to be created with GLU set (env variable GL_USEGLU=1) for the server to accept that codepoint. 'U+0760' corresponds to 0xDDA0 in UTF-8 and I don't see that included in the GLS UTF-8 encoding file. You mentioned that it works with 'dbaccess'. Is that when having CLIENT_LOCALE set to en_US.UTF8 or without it?.  I expect a -202 'Illegal character' error if CLIENT_LOCALE was set.  I ran a quick test with an UTF8 database created with GLU and had no errors updating or selecting that character with JDBC. An 'oncheck  -pp' shows the correct 0xDDA0 in the table.

Comment: @jsagrera: Set env variable GL_USEGLU=1 solved the problem.
Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @jsagrera: if you don't mind to have a look at my other Informix JDBC question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69927319/how-to-pass-array-of-integer-to-informix-stored-procedure. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with UTF-8 Informix databases is recommended to use the ICU libraries rather than the Informix GLS ones because ICU supports a more wider range.
To enable ICU use make sure the GL_USEGLU environment variable is set to either 1 or 4 before the server is started and the database is created.

More info here:
https://informix.hcldoc.com/14.10/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.glsug.doc%2Fids_gug_063.htm

Depending on your API (like JDBC or .NET) you may also need to include GL_USEGLU in the connection string for it to work properly.